# How to configure setup for Django 2.2.8 on Shared or VPS Hosting

Tags: django

I am trying to configure web server for Django 2.2.8 on VPS Server as well as Shared Hosting but both are not working. I have configure python on the web server and its shell is working and giving output . But when I am trying to configure Django but its not working Its Giving the blank screen.

I have followed these steps for Django Configuration and followed this link

```
https://github.com/sparagus/django-shared-hosting-1and1
```

Access your server via SSH, which will most likely take you to your base directory (your htdocs directory where the directories to your websites are).

```
Make a directory where you want your Python files to reside and cd into it.

mkdir python_files

cd python_files

Run the build-python.sh

./build-python.sh

install/python3.6.3/bin/python3 -m venv venv

source venv/bin/activate

pip install --upgrade pip

pip install -r requirements.txt
If you get an SSL error here then there's a problem with OpenSSL.

Check if Django is installed correctly.

python -m django --version


Go back to your base directory and start a Django project.

cd ..

django-admin startproject your_site
```

**and so on followed all the steps which are mentioned on the git link but it is showing blank when accessing the url**

Comment: You'll need to give more information. A blank page isn't necessarily a bad thing, at least it's not an error. In your browser debug tools, network tab, look at the exact response you get. Is it HTTP 200 OK? What's the response body? Also, if you have ssh access to your host, are you able to view the Apache logs? And the syslog? There should be logs so you can investigate further.

Comment: One question though: Why are you following this tutorial? Does your hosting provider not give you a virtual machine with root access? It would be much easier to host your app on such an environment, as you can then just follow the [official guides](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/). Choose another hosting provider if you don't have root access.

Comment: @dirkgroten it shows Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) in the console tab

Comment: But in the network tab?

Comment: @dirkgroten still shows 500 error in the network tab

Comment: Then you have to find the logs to understand why